# Boost Asio share same io_service along disposible objects

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I'm developing a program, which consists of bunch of Active Objects, that sending messages to each other. I'm using one same io_service to initialize all these objects. So they're working to end of the software life.

I'm using the Active Objects ,let's say, one for file operation, another for serial IO, another for local database connection and one to communicate all of these.

However I couldn't be sure about the objects with short lives. I'm using the short lived objects to open tcp socket to send a quick message to a remote endpoint then dispose the socket immediately. I'm thinking to make these also asynchronous.

The question is, should I use the same io_service for these short lived objects or should I create a new io_service for each socket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm developing a program, which consists of bunch of Active Objects, that sending messages to each other. I'm using one same io_service to initialize all these objects. So they're working to end of the software life.

Sounds like a good fit. I would recommend using Chris Kohlhoff's [recipe](https://think-async.com/Asio/Recipes) if you need operations to be more efficient on machines with multiple processors.

> However I couldn't be sure about the objects with short lives. I'm using the short lived objects to open tcp socket to send a quick message to a remote endpoint then dispose the socket immediately. I'm thinking to make these also asynchronous.

There's nothing wrong with having few(er)long-lived asio io_service objects (e.g. you could create the same number of io_services as there are processors on the machine), and short lived objects that use the io_service.  I would say this is more efficient as well since you don't have to fire-up a thread to call `io_service::run` on each (short-lived?) io_service and you can avoid unnecessary context switching.

Making the sockets asynchronous is also needed if you want/need to avoid blocking in your thread(s), especially if there are network issues, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Ralf , I'd like to ask another one. I generate the short lived object inside one of the Active objects, what is the suitable way to share same io_service? I've shared with direct address of io_service object to reuse it. But I don't like this C way.

Comment: By "C way" I assume you mean pointers? I prefer to pass io_service references (io_service& ) around and store them.  This does mean that you need to have a constructor that takes an io_service argument and initialises the member reference.